# Why isn't utorrent working? How do I remedy this problem?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, bittorrent, dell-vostro, utorrent

I tried to install utorrent by following the instructions available at http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/01/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/ but when I got to the step of typing:

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

into terminal I received the output:

```
server started - using locale en_AU.UTF-8
Using locale en_AU.UTF-8
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat.old
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat.old
Failed file save: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/settings.dat.new
total physical memory -1 max disk cache 33554432
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/dht.dat
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/dht.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/dht.dat.old
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/rss.dat
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/rss.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/rss.dat.old
TCP port bind failed 0.0.0.0:6881: (98) Address already in use
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/resume.dat
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/resume.dat.new
File not found during integrity check: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/resume.dat.old
IPv6 is installed
```

and then after a day of it stuck at this point it still hadn't installed the utorrent server.

I am using 12.10 i386 on a Dell Vostro 3500 laptop if any further details are required.

Comment: have you tried running it with elevated permissions? ie sudo or gksudo

Comment: No, thanks, I am trying it now. Will tell ya in a few hours if it works.

Comment: @RickGreen continuously receive the error: Failed file save: /opt/utorrent-server-v3.0/resume.dat.new
Unable to save the resume file. Another program might have the file open, or the disk is full.

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure utorrent to save to your ~/home/"some_folder other than /opt. This again would be a permissions issue as /opt is a ROOT folder and should not be used for read-write options. Suggest you run `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/` again then retry.

Comment: @RickGreen Retried after running that code in terminal and I received the same error.

Comment: "chmod 777 /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/"<br>
type "ls -l" after to make sure you have the permissions to write to the folder. <br><br>My utorrent generates the settings.dat files automatically on startup, they are not required to start the app

Comment: Is it have to be Utorrent what about trying other program like transmission .

Comment: why don't you try deluge to download torrent files

Comment: hey mate, i know this isn't the answer to your question, but i`m a heavy torrent user and I would highly recommend you to use some other client (Tixati/Deluge).. Tixati is a bit more complex and requires more tinkering to make it work properly, but Deluge is really user friendly, no ads and looks a lot like uTorrent. uTorrent went down a path that I don't like, using a lot of resources and sometimes i feel it clicks ads in the background without telling you about it, so I personally don't trust them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me, after a few tries, this is what helped me:

1. I check how many servers were running with the command `ps -e`
2. Then, ended all the server process with `killall -v utserver`
3. Then, I start it again with `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ &` Notice the `&` at the end, to tell the terminal, to process it in the background. Also, notice the ending `/` slash, so it knows it true path.

You may want to check it, running again `ps -e`.

**Note**: I do have to run the last command, every time I turn on my computer. But that's logic, cause it's a service we need to start.

Comment: I am still facing the same error. Any other possible solution please

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The missing files got copied to my `home` folder instead of the `opt` folder. Just check your `home` folder, copy the missing files and paste them in the `opt` folder using Nautilus or whatever suits you.